# ABPersonCreate UINavigationController buttons handle

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have this code that open the add person page , but when I tap on "done" or "cancel" buttons nothing happens.

What am I missing ?

I need when user tap "done" to save to contact list ,and when "cancel" back to Previous view.

```
-(void)moveToAddContactButton
{
ABRecordRef newPerson= ABPersonCreate();
CFErrorRef error = NULL;

ABMutableMultiValueRef multiPhone = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);

NSString *phoneNumber =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",theUser.symboNumber];

ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiPhone, (__bridge CFTypeRef)(phoneNumber), kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel, NULL);
ABRecordSetValue(newPerson, kABPersonPhoneProperty, multiPhone,nil);
NSAssert(!error, @"something bad happend here.");


ABNewPersonViewController* newPersonViewController = [[ABNewPersonViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[newPersonViewController setDisplayedPerson:newPerson];
[newPersonViewController setNewPersonViewDelegate:self];


UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:newPersonViewController];

[self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];


CFRelease(newPerson);
```

}

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I change form UINavigationController to ABPeoplePickerNavigationController  and it solved my problem.

after that I add didCompleteWithNewPerson to handel taps on buttons.

-(void)moveToAddContactButton
    {
    ABRecordRef newPerson= ABPersonCreate();
    CFErrorRef error = NULL;

```
ABMutableMultiValueRef multiPhone = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);

NSString *phoneNumber =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",theUser.symboNumber];

ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiPhone, (__bridge CFTypeRef)(phoneNumber), kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel, NULL);
ABRecordSetValue(newPerson, kABPersonPhoneProperty, multiPhone,nil);

NSAssert(!error, @"something bad happend here.");


ABNewPersonViewController* newPersonViewController = [[ABNewPersonViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[newPersonViewController setDisplayedPerson:newPerson];
[newPersonViewController setNewPersonViewDelegate:self];


ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *navController = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:newPersonViewController];

[self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];


CFRelease(newPerson);

}
```

:

```
-(void)newPersonViewController:(ABNewPersonViewController *)newPersonView didCompleteWithNewPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```